# Is restriction of $exp:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^*$ to $A = \{ x+iy : x \in R, y \in ]1, 1+2\pi]\} \subset \mathbb{C}$ a bijection?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have this question:

> Is the restriction of exp function $exp:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^*$ to $A = \{ x+iy : x \in R, y \in ]1, 1+2\pi]\} \subset \mathbb{C}$ a bijection?

Here's what I tried:

> True because :
>
> $e^z = e^x(\cos y + i\sin y)$
>
> $e^x$ is bijective in $\mathbb{R}$
>
> There isn't any number differing of $2k\pi$ in $]1, 1+2\pi]$. So $i\sin y$ is bijective and $\cos x$ is bijective. We can then say that:
>
> $e^z:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^*$ is a bijection.

What do you think about this answer?

Comment: Anyway, here are a couple of tips (I would rather have somebody else answer this question). First, when you say that a function is bijective (or injective, or surjective...), always specify its domain and codomain. Sentences such as "$e^x$ is bijective" or "$i \sin (y)$ is bijective" otherwise make not sense. Second, if you want a clean and nonsense-free proof, separate the injectivity and the surjectivity.

Comment: @d-thomine Ok thanks for the tips.